# Django REST Framework ManyToMany Field Error

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I am working with an existing database and wish to create a ManyToMany relationship between two tables. The abbreviated code is:

```
class AddressSummary(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'addresses'
        app_label = 'myapp'

    address_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='addr_id', primary_key=True)
    partial_matches = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='ReferenceAddress',
        through='AddressMatches'
    )
    @property
    def get_partial_matches(self):
        try:
            return self.partial_matches.all()
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)


class ReferenceAddress(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'reference_addresses'
        app_label = 'myapp'

    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    family_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    type_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    partial_matches = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='AddressOverview',
        through='AddressMatches',
    )


class AddressMatches(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'partial_matches'
        unique_together = (('addr_id', 'ref_id'),)
        app_label = 'myapp'

    addr_id = models.ForeignKey('AddressSummary', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='addr_id', to_field='address_id')
    ref_id = models.ForeignKey('ReferenceAddress', models.DO_NOTHING, to_field='id')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'addresssummary' into field. Choices are: family_name, id, partial_matches, type_name
```

Any ideas? I have tried reordering the classes but this doesn't help.
If I wrap the failing line into a try/except clause, it returns the following exception:

```
'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'
```

Comment: This problem appears when you execute migrate?

Comment: No, I have a serializer which returns an AddressSummary. The error happens when I call self.partial_matches.all() in a property of an instance of the AddressSummary class. The goal is to return the family_names of the reference addresses with the summary.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us how your serializer looks like.

Missing informations make answerers to guess harder what's going on, and your chance of getting answer goes down..

With the limited info,

> Cannot resolve keyword 'addresssummary' into field. Choices are:
>   family_name, id, partial_matches, type_name
>
> The error happens when I call self.partial_matches.all() in a property
>   of an instance of the AddressSummary class

You are saying that your `self` in `self.partial_matches.all()` is AddressSummary instance, but the error shows all the fields of `ReferenceAddress` suggesting the `self` is actually `ReferenceAddress`.

You might start from that.

Comment: The error happens before any serialization so I didn't include it. I have modified the code above. I can't show everything unfortunately. The get_partial_matches property is used by other properties not shown.